# Directional derivative definition versus gradient

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, scalar-fields

> Given the following scalar field
> $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
>            \frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y)\ne(0,0) \\
>             0 & (x,y)=(0,0)
>            \end{cases}$$
> find its directional derivative in the direction of $(3,2)$ at the point $(0,0)$.

---

First way I wanted to do this was with the gradient. However, as neither partial derivative exists at $(0,0)$, I need to use their limit form instead:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{0}{h^3}=0$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(0,k)-f(0)}{k}=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(0,k)}{k}=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{k^3}{k^3}=1$$

Yielding my gradient at $(0,0)$:

$$\nabla f = \vec{(0, 1)}$$

Using this to calculate the directional derivative with $u = (3,2)$, I get

$$\nabla_{u} f(0,0)=\nabla f_{(0,0)}\frac{u}{|u|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}(3,2)\cdot{}(0,1)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}$$

However, if I use the directional derivative definition here:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\vec{a}+h\vec{u})-f(\vec{a})}{h|u|}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h(3,2))}{h\sqrt{13}}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{(2h)^3}{(3h)^2+(2h)^2}}{h\sqrt{13}}=\frac{8}{13\sqrt{13}}$$

which was the gradient answer but cubed. What should I expect from these answers? And what have I done wrong that yields these different but similar answers?

Comment: The formula $\nabla_u f(0,0)=\nabla f_{(0,0)} u$ is valid if $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: The function you deal with is the typical example of a function whose partial derivatives exists but which is not differentiable. So the formula that i mentionned is not valid for the function, so that it's "normal" that you have different answers.

Comment: @SacAndSac I have actually "proved" that it ia differentiable at (0,0) later in my task. Is my answer here then wrong? Is it actually not differentiable at(0,0)? To do this i calculated the limit with:
$$\lim_{|r|->0}(\frac{f(0+r)-L(0+r)}{|r|})=0$$
and got that LHS = RHS aka 0 = 0 and it was differentiable.
Is this the wrong way  to check for differentiability

Comment: The function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$, you probably did a mistake somewhere (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions)

Comment: @SacAndSac Thanks for your answer :D

Comment: If you plot the graph of the function, for example [using Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=plot+y%5E3%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29), then do you think it *looks* differentiable at the origin?

Comment: "However, as neither partial derivative exists..." - You have shown that both partial derivatives exist, haven't you?

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is NOT differentiable at $(0,0)$. According to the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions), the following limit should be zero,
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-\nabla f_{(0,0)}\cdot (x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2} -y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{-yx^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}.$$
It turns out that this limit does not exist. It is $0$ along $y=0$ or $x=0$. On the other hand, for $y=x$, as $x\to 0^+$, we find
$$\frac{-yx^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{-y^3}{(2y^2)^{3/2}}\to -\frac{1}{2^{3/2}}\not=0.$$
Therefore, without the differentiability condition, the equality
$$\nabla_{u} f(0,0)=\nabla f_{(0,0)}\cdot \frac{u}{|u|}$$
may not be satisfied (as shown in your work).